# Pulling the MINIMUM Date

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to join two tables together, that only share an "Account Number" as a joining field between them.  One table (Table1) is static and contains just one record per account number, but the other joining table (Table2) contains multiple Date records per account number.  Using a Temp Table, I'm trying to first pull distinct Date records from Table2 and then join them to Table1 via the Account Number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(tlpsf.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS NCHAR(16)) AS psAccountNumber
    ,tlpsf.APPL_ID AS psApplID
    --,MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),tlpsf.DATE_PYMT_DUE_FIRST,120)) AS psDatePmtDueFirst
    ,MIN(CAST(tlpsf.DATE_PYMT_DUE_FIRST AS datetime2)) AS psDatePmtDueFirst
    ,tlpsf.NBR_OF_PMTS_THIS_SCHEDULE AS psNbrPmtsThisSchedule
    , CAST(tlpsf.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT AS NUMERIC(17,2)) AS psPmtScheduleAmt
    , tlpsf.PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE AS psPmtScheduleType
    , tlpsf.ROW_PROCESSED_THRU AS psRowProcessedThru

INTO #loanpmtschedules
FROM dbo.T_LOAN_PYMT_SCHEDULE_FILE_ME tlpsf
WHERE tlpsf.ROW_PROCESSED_THRU = @strLastofMonth
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER, APPL_ID, NBR_OF_PMTS_THIS_SCHEDULE, PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_AMOUNT, PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_TYPE, ROW_PROCESSED_THRU
```

However, for some reason my Temp table build is still pulling in multiple date records, per account number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to assign a row number to each row in `Table2` grouped by `AccountNumber` and ordered by `PaymentDate`.  We are then able to join `Table1` with `Table2` on `AccountNumber` where the row number from `Table2` is 1 meaning the minimum payment date for each account.

```
--demo setup
Declare @Table1 table (AccountNumber int)
Declare @Table2 table (AccountNumber int, PaymentDate date, OtherStuff varchar(50))

insert into @Table1 (AccountNumber) values(1)
insert into @Table1 (AccountNumber) values(2)
insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(1,'2019-01-01','jan')
insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(1,'2019-02-01','feb')
insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(1,'2019-02-01','mar')

insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(2,'2019-05-01','may')
insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(2,'2019-06-01','jun')
insert into @Table2 (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, OtherStuff) values(2,'2019-07-01','jul')

--solution
SELECT t1.AccountNumber
    ,t2.PaymentDate
    ,OtherStuff
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY PaymentDate
            ) AS rn
    FROM @Table2
    ) t2
    ON t2.AccountNumber = t1.AccountNumber
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

---

```
| AccountNumber | PaymentDate | OtherStuff |
|---------------|-------------|------------|
| 1             | 2019-01-01  | jan        |
| 2             | 2019-05-01  | may        |
```

Comment: Wow, I've definitely never seen that approach before but it worked PERFECT.  I have soooo much to learn.  THANK YOU!

Comment: You are welcome.